# Pass as string for JS with django not working

Tags: javascript, django

The table I have so far, when rendered, properly displays the job numbers which are formatted individually as:
'15-215' or '15-552'

I want to pass each job number on the table so that when I click each TD it passes the job number into my javascript.  It took me a while to diagnose that I need to pass as string otherwise it will evaluate 15-215 and then pass that.

My html document is like below:

```
    {% for a in obj %}
    ...

 <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" class="accordion-toggle">

        <td onclick="test(\'' + {{a.jobnum}} + '\')">{{a.jobnum}}</td>
    ...
    {% endfor %}
```

My js is like:

```
function test(y) {
  alert(y);
  document.getElementById("123").innerHTML = y;
  }
```

I then have:

```
<p id="123">1</p>
```

But when I click the relevant td I get neither an alert nor the `<p>` updating

Answer (score 0):

I would do this a little bit different:

**template**

```
{% for a in obj %}
    ...

<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" class="accordion-toggle">

   <td data-jobnum='{{ a.jobnum }}' class="test">{{a.jobnum}}</td>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

**js(jquery)**

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).data('jobnum');
    alert(value);
})
```

Now you can do any javascript with the `value`.

**Note**

I used Jquery but you can do this with js also.